# Magento 2, How to Display Demo store message on home page only?

Tags: magento2, messages

In Magento 2.4.x, How to Display Demo store message on specific page (home page) only?

Answer (score 0):

We can show the message on any page using the page identifiers.

To show the message on the home page only. Try using the below code:

```
<?php
$moduleName = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
$controllerName = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$actionName = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
$pageIdentifier = $moduleName.'_'.$controllerName .'_'.$actionName;

if($pageIdentifier == 'cms_index_index'){
    echo "Your Message Here!";
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you!